# I want to add a record to mySQL database after validating user input

Tags: php, html, sql

My form is very basic and the requirements are as follows - take user input, validate user input,add a new record to mySQL database, display a confirmation page.

I can do all of the previously mentioned requirements. However, after validation how do i get the page to redirect to another php file and not just keep redirecting to itself. At the minute i am using PHP_SELF to prompt the user if a field is missing.

```
<form id="new_event" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">   
    <fieldset>
```

Comment: try PHP_SELF... you have a typo

Comment: Better yet, drop the whole `action` value (or even the attribute). The default is to submit to self.